# Express.js Helmet CSP settings with Cloudflare - what to put in?

Tags: express, heroku, cloudflare, helmet.js

I deployed a simple portfolio site on Heroku (free tier). The site is built with Express Node.js and React for frontend. To use my .dev domain which requires SSL, I signed up for Cloudflare. Now everything works except my sending email form. I get the following error:

`` Refused to connect to `https://<my-app>.herokuapp.com/api/v1/email/sendemail' because it violates the following Contect Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. ``

I figured out it's something with helmet and CSP policies, but I don't understand what exactly I need to put in there.
As a temporary solution I disabled CSP like this:

```js
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: false,
  })
);
```

But ideally I want to do something like this:

```js
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
        'connect-src': ["'self'", 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com'],
      },
    },
  })
);
```

But I don't know what to put in there. Neither cdnjs.cloudflare.com nor ajax.cloudflare.com work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are most common usages with CSP in Express. This is configuration of my app, I think you should find there everything you need:

```
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        blockAllMixedContent: [],
        fontSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', 'data:'],
        frameAncestors: ["'self'", 'https://accounts.google.com/'],
        frameSrc: ["'self'", 'https://accounts.google.com/'],
        imgSrc: ["'self'", 'data:'],
        objectSrc: ["'self'", 'blob:'],
        mediaSrc: ["'self'", 'blob:', 'data:'],
        scriptSrc: ["'self'", 'https://apis.google.com'],
        scriptSrcAttr: ["'none'"],
        styleSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', "'unsafe-inline'"],
        upgradeInsecureRequests: [],
        connectSrc: ["'self'", 'https://my-app.herokuapp.com'],
      },
    },
  })
);
```

Your `connectSrc` should include `https://my-app.herokuapp.com`, just like you see on last line.

Comment: I was really confused and I thought connectSrc has to be some Cloudflare address. Turns out it has to be my heroku app...Oh well, thank you, very helpful response!